# i have a web api and i want to implement remote config in my base how i will save api endpoint in remote config and then want to call that api

Tags: android, firebase

I have a web API and I have displayed the data using asynctask and I have integrated firebase in my app, I want to implement remote config in my base how I will save API endpoint in the remote config and then want to call that API.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6QdSsW8mQdOajZWRDd6eHBKN1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a moment to learn what our site is for by taking the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2018, there is now a [REST API](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/03/announcing-remote-config-rest-api.html) available for you to communicate with the Remote Config service. You should probably check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest) on how to get started.